# Appending clone to a div by for loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below javascript code is for cloning the `clonedInput1`. But below code only creating and appends one clone. But year_no is 3.

```
cloneid = 0;
function clone_year(year_no)
{
    cloneid += 1;
    var container = document.getElementById('clone_div');
    var clone = $('#clonedInput1').clone();
    for (i = 0; i < year_no; i++) {
        $('.clone_div').append(clone);
    }
}
```

This is the html code for above code.

```
<div id="year_sem_details" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="clone_div" id="clone_div">
            <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput row">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- here some html -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please Help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
cloneid = 0;
function clone_year(year_no)
{
    cloneid += 1;
    var container = document.getElementById('clone_div');
    //var clone = $('#clonedInput1').clone();
    for (i = 0; i < year_no; i++) {
        $('.clone_div').append($('#clonedInput1').clone());
    }
}

clone_year(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year_sem_details" style="display:block">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="clone_div" id="clone_div">
            <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput row">1
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- here some html -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an ID selector like `$('#clonedInput1').clone()` so you will append a **new** element on each iteration:

```js
function clone_year(year_no)
{
    var container = document.getElementById('clone_div');
    var clone = $('#clonedInput1').clone();
    for (i = 0; i < year_no; i++) {
        $('#clone_div').append($('#clonedInput1').clone());
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="clone_div" id="clone_div">
        <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput row">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type='button' onclick='clone_year(3);' value='go' />
```

Comment: but `.html()` may not copy the events of the element if they had?

Comment: why do we need `var clone=...` if we clone it in loop :)

Answer (score 1):

You're appending the **same element** (`clone`) to `$('.clone_div')`. For each iteration, clone a new element.

```
for (i = 0; i < year_no; i++) {
    $('.clone_div').append($('#clonedInput1').clone());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/u5zw67v3/

```js
cloneid = 1;
function clone_year(year_no) {
  for (i = 0; i < year_no; i++) {
    cloneid++;
    $('.clone_div').append($('#clonedInput1').clone());
    $('.clone_div').find('.clonedInput').last().attr('id', 'clonedInput' + cloneid);
  }
}

clone_year(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year_sem_details">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="clone_div" id="clone_div">
            <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput row">
                <div class="row">
                    here some html
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `id` should be unique.

Hope this will help you.